# How to not mount a component for every conditional rendering React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

I have a conditional rendering where I render a `Child` component which have states. The case is that every time I render the `Child` component from `Father` component, the `Child` is mounted and it's state is reset. I don't want to reset the states inside, how can I do it?

```js
const Father = () => {
  const [fatherState, setFatherState] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    {!fatherState ? <Child /> : <p>Hello</p>}
    
    <button onClick={() => setFatherState(!fatherState)}>Change father state</button>
    <p>Father state: {fatherState}</p>
  )
}

const Child = () => {
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState(0);
  
  return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => setChildState(childState + 1)}>Change child state</button>
            <p>Child state: {childState}</p>
        </>
    );
}
```

Any help is welcomed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it, because you are having a condition to render Child and whenever the condition is false Child will be unmounted and again mounted in condition true (so all Child states will be gone), so the only way might be just to define child states in parent component and pass to Child as props, or use state management like redux or context

Answer (score -1):

`{!fatherState ? <Child /> : <p>Hello</p>}` This is your problem, your adding and removing child, so of course state is lost. If you want to keep the state of Child, you could maybe set the component's display property to none instead.

Below is an example, where I pass a prop called vis, that makes the child visible..

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Father = () => {
  const [fatherState, setFatherState] = useState(false);
  
  return (<React.Fragment>
    {!fatherState && <p>Hello</p>}
    <Child vis={fatherState}/>
    
    <button onClick={() => setFatherState(!fatherState)}>Change father state</button>
    <p>Father state: {fatherState}</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const Child = ({vis}) => {
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState(0);
  
  return (
        <div style={{display: vis ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
            <button onClick={() => setChildState(childState + 1)}>Change child state</button>
            <p>Child state: {childState}</p>
        </div>
    );
}


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Father/>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant do that because you are mounting/unmounting your component while using ternary operator however you can change your code like

```
const Father = () => {
  const [fatherState, setFatherState] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Child fatherState={fatherState} />
      {!fatherState && <p>Hello</p>}
      <button onClick={() => setFatherState(!fatherState)}>
        Change father state
      </button>
      <p>Father state: {fatherState}</p>
    </>
  );
};

const Child = (props) => {
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState(0);
  const { fatherState } = props;
  return (
    <div style={{ visibility: fatherState ? "visible" : "hidden" }}>
      <button onClick={() => setChildState(childState + 1)}>
        Change child state
      </button>
      <p>Child state: {childState}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```